# mongodb can't start with Assertion: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb

my instance running in docker. after close it uncleanly, it can't be started. with log below

```
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13 port=27017
dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=94a9490feef9ce51e9e55af47ab5c357-a0000
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian71
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { port: 27017 }, security: { authorization: "disabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/db", directoryPerDB: true, journal: { enabled: true } } }
I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=150G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:2: No such file or directory
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 2: No such file or directory, terminating
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

which file can't be found is not show, how to deal next?

Comment: same error here... did you find a workaround?